# Relative stability of cis and trans cycloalkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, isomers, cis-trans-isomerism

Why is the stability of (*Z*)-cyclodecene **2** greater than that of (*E*)-cyclodecene **1**?

[image]

I'd think that since **1** contains a *trans* double bond instead of a *cis* double bond, it should experience less steric repulsion and hence be more stable.

However, I've read that the *cis* isomer **2** is more stable than the *trans* isomer **1** if the ring size is 11 or smaller. For ring sizes larger than 11, the opposite is true.

Why is this so? Also, what would happen if there were more double bonds?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Usually *trans*-olefins are more stable than their *cis* isomers for steric reasons, like you suggested.  However in small and medium size rings this is not the case; here the *cis*-cycloalkene is more stable than the corresponding  *trans* isomer.

*trans*-Cyclooctene is the smallest trans-cycloalkene that is stable at room temperature (*trans*-cyclohexene and *trans*-cycloheptene have been detected as short-lived intermediates).  In your drawing up above of *trans*-cyclodecene (a) draw in the two hydrogens on the *trans* double bond.  One of them is "inside" the ring and causes steric problems with the carbons on the other side of the ring as pictured below.  Because of this destabilizing transannular interaction *trans*-cycloalkenes with up to around 11 carbons do not exist as planar molecules.  They exist in a conformation as pictured below for *trans*-cyclooctene.

[image]

([image source](http://www.organicchemistry.com/cycloalkenes-and-cycloalkynes/))

If you can, build a model of *trans*-cyclooctene.  Notice how you have to pull and stretch the methylene chain in order to attach that last methylene back onto the other end of the double bond - there is a lot of strain in this molecule. Now build a model of *cis*-cyclooctene; it is easy to loop the methylene chain from one end of the double bond to the other end.

Not until you get to around *trans*-cyclododecene (12 carbons) do you have enough carbons to easily connect from one end of the *trans* double bond back to the other end.  ***trans*-Cycloalkenes with less than 12 carbons have additional strain because of this difficulty in spanning the double bond**. Once you get to around 12 carbons there is no difficulty spanning the double bond and so once again *trans*-cycloalkenes become more stable than their *cis* counterparts.

Since double bond carbons are $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybridized with 120° angles, if we add more double bonds, the 120° angles make it more difficult to loop the more flexible $\mathrm{sp^3}$ methylene (with their 109.5° angles) chain around the double bonds.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you, but I was also wondering if there was a way to understand this without making a model (although it would certainly make it easier to understand)?

Comment: Just try to imagine how hard it would be to loop the methylene chain from one end of a trans double bond to the other, when the chain is relatively short.

Comment: In figure b of the question, wouldn't the 2 sp3 hydrogens from both sides contribute to hindrance?

Comment: @Mixcels  Yes, probably some, but the big effect is from having to "stretch" 6 carbons from one end of the double bond to the other.

Comment: The problem with figure b here is that it's wrong. The lowest energy conformer is a crown conformation, it's hard to draw but this one isn't one. you really need to look at it in 3D like here http://comporgchem.com/blog/?p=1709 . The strain itself isn't a big problem, those are quite stable too.